# How to get object instead of string from dropdown list in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

On my JSP page i have following dropdown list:

```
<form:select path="companies" name="company">
<form:options items="${companies}" itemValue="name" itemLabel="name"/>
</form:select>
```

This list displays name attribute of Company object. when I choose value and submit form, my controller receive this attribute.

I looking for way to how to receive this object in controller instead of single attribute.

Comment: after getting `name` fire a query for Object..

Comment: I know I can do that way, but I'm looking for how to get this object from jsp. 
Is it even possible?

Comment: You can use data-binding. Check https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-dropdown-box-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first of all I recommend having the company id, if there is one, instead of company name as the value that will we submitted from the drop down.  You can still display the name as the description but send the id as the value.  An id would usually be the primary key in your company table, if you have one.  Names are not very unique.

Then when you receive this id as a parameter in your spring controller method you will get a handle to the same list that was used to render the drop down and get the object. The thing about spring is that object models only persist as long as the request by default, so the list you used to render the drop down would have disappeared by the time the user sends the id back.  The first request was used to render the page, and the second request is the sending of the parameter.  So, you will want to persist this list in memory longer than the request.  You can make that list persist longer by keeping it in the session.  Spring has an annotation for making model attributes persist at session level.  Just keep in mind that the object will then live in the session as long as the user is logged in unless you remove it.

I kind of wonder why you want the object.  Often times the id is all you need because you set that in the db as the users company of choice and you are all set.  However, I can't tell what you are trying to do.